# Android - Protecting the privacy of users with a keyboard app

Tags: android, android-permissions, privacy, user-data

I have developed a keyboard app for Android. It's a free app so it has in-app advertisements to earn some revenue. To run these advertisements, I need the internet permission for my app. As a keyboard app, users type a lot of sensitive information from this app. They always ask me whether their privacy is protected or not. I don't collect anything they type from this keyboard. Only the reason I have internet permission is to run ads & it is necessary to earn revenue. I know it's impossible to remove internet permission at runtime because it's declared in the manifest file. If it was possible I could add a premium version which doesn't have the internet permission.

Can anyone give me any idea to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this would be using Flavours. You can learn about Flavours and if they are best suited to you need by reading: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants